root and efi mounted as external HDD - Ubuntu 20.04
After inserting a corrupted USB stick trying to format it, sometimes root and /boot/efi partitions were mounted as external HDD, as in this picture
This problem isn't happening at any boot but only sometimes. When it happens, I got a black screen after user login and then I have to wait several minutes to have the desktop and file explorer working normal.
Other times the boot is clean and after login the file explorer is ready in seconds and non of those disk are mounted.
This is my fstab configuration:
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme1n1p3 during installation
UUID=b1d7cebc-7e3b-4482-82e8-b88c0bf7ca10       /       ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=DA47-EB38  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# swap was on /dev/nvme1n1p2 during installation
UUID=4710f05f-3033-4a2b-8696-ac9c764b4b30 none            swap    sw              0       0

